# Simple Greasemonkey Script Crashing Browser

Tags: javascript, function

I was hoping someone could help me figure out why this script is crashing the browser. The first 4 loop has about 20 elements and the second has 8. I didn't think that would be enough to crash it, but I could be wrong.

I am trying to scrape data values out of a table to then use to create a custom graph on the page.

Any help on design is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

```
function mainFunc() {
  var b;
  var a;
  var x;
  var y;
  var c;
  var times = [];
  var mainTable = document.getElementsByClassName("reportTable tabularReportTable");
  var rows = mainTable[0].getElementsByClassName("breakRowClass1 breakRowClassBottom");
  for (x = 0; x < rows.length; x++) {
    a = rows[x].children;
    for (y = 0; y < a.length; x++) {
      if (a[y].innerHTML !== "&nbsp;") {
        b = a[y].innerHTML.split("<");
        c  = parseFloat(b[0]);
        times.push(c);
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're increment the y for loop by increment the variable x, `x++` instead of `y++`.

```
for (y = 0; y < a.length; x++) {
```

Should be:

```
for (y = 0; y < a.length; y++) {
```